# How can I use Reveal.js in Rails 6?

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, reveal.js

In my gemfile I have:

```
gem 'revealjs-rails',
```

which should be working for Rails.

I am thinking that it was developed for Rails 4 and maybe that is why I cannot use it. In my terminal I get:

```
ERROR in ./app/javascript/style/application.sass (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--7-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--7-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--7-3!./app/javascript/style/application.sass)

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):

@import 'revealjs'
^

File to import not found or unreadable: revealjs.
in /Users/adelmuursepp/webdev/adel_portfolio_site/app/javascript/style/application.sass (line 9, column 1)
```

My application is here:

https://github.com/adelmuursepp/adel_portfolio_site